# How do I add CSS classes in "Content type > Manage Display >Table of files"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

In Drupal 9, I can create a new field called file in some content type, e.g. in Article.

Then for this new field in Manage Display I can select Format Settings: File Table.

Finally, I can add a new page (Article type) and attach some files.
After saving, I have a page with a table.

My question: how do I add a class to this table? I know I can add styles in css stylesheets, but maybe there is a way to add a class directly to the table in a node?
I mean node not View. It just so happens that for View I already know how to do it. But I don't know how to do this for Node

Thank you

ok

Answer (score 0):

The hooks are there for that. If you want to update the node renderable array, you can use the preprocess hook :

```
/**
  * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
  */
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  $node = $variables['node'];

  if ($node->bundle() == 'article'
    && $variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    // $variables['content']['files']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class';
  }
}
```

In your case, you want to update the field, it might be cleaner to edit the field directly :

```
/**
  * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
  */
function your_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

}
```